# iphone idle timer check for after a particular event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, uiapplication, idle-timer

Here am developing a application which i should start this idle timer event after the user is get signed in and i should stop this event after the user is signout the application.

Here i have implemented a logic like subclassing the UIApplication and detecting the touch event.

But the problem here is this will only work when user is tapping something.
this singing and sign out involve web service. so if signing fails i have to stop this idle timer. At present am checking a condition like user signed in or not and then am calling idle exceed method.

So here i have to call the **sendEvent:uiEvent** method manually after the user is signed.
is there any possible way there to call this default method for starting idle time checking.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what do you need the idle timer for? please explain more :)

Comment: this is it i have to trigger this sendEvent method after a particular period of time say for example 2mins. is it possible ? this is to trigger idle timer start.

Comment: do you just need a function to be called after 2 seconds?

Comment: I just want to know how to call sendEvent: method manually which is subclassed from uiapplication

Answer (score 0):

To call sendEvent manually do the following

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendEvent:YOUR_EVENT]
```